# How to insert (create) data (CRUD) FORM in blade in multiple languages into database and read it out with LARAVEL MULTILANGUAGE - LOCALIZE?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, localization, multilingual

I have followed this tutorial *(https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-build-an-efficient-and-seo-friendly-multilingual-architecture-for-your-laravel-application)* about laravel multilanguage and localization. Everything seems ok, except I want to CREATE a CRUD for inserting this posts with title and content in multiple language - and STORE it in database - and then read it out in index blade.

Can you show me an example of CRUD in this way in blade for CREATE and in Controller for CREATE and STORE function. How to make this to work?

This is my simple main CRUD, how to extend this to be able to creating and storing into multiple language when creating. 
And how to extend the controller for storing in multiple language when using this translatable package from tutorial above (link).

**CRUD:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {

        $post = Post::all();

        $this->validate(request(), [

            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required'

        ]);

        $post = new Post;

        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->content = $request->content;

        $post->save();

          return redirect('/');
```

THANKS :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not for you to find a mentor on how to program, but to share what you have tried and doesn't work so someone can point you out in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @nakov, thank you on your answer, but please I am a little bit confused I have main form for create in blade but how to create in multiple language when I have installed everything for localization followed the tutorial above.

This is my simple CRUD, how to extend this in the way to create and store 2 multiple language and also what to change in Controller. (UPDATED IN QUESTION).

Comment: @nakov, You can help me now. Thanks

Comment: There it is my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS WORKING WELL IN THIS SITUATION:

CONTROLLER:

```
public function create()
   {

       return view('services.new');

   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {

  $service = new Service();

   $service->save();
$this->validate($request, [

           'title2' => 'required|max:350',
           'content2' => 'required'
         ]);

     foreach (['en', 'bs'] as $locale) {

           $service->translateOrNew('en')->title = $request->title;
           $service->translateOrNew('en')->content = $request->content; 
           $service->translateOrNew('bs')->title = $request->title2;
           $service->translateOrNew('bs')->content = $request->content2; 

       }


       $service->translateOrNew('en')->title = $request->title;
       $service->translateOrNew('en')->content = $request->content;  
       $service->translateOrNew('bs')->title = $request->title2;
       $service->translateOrNew('bs')->content = $request->content2; 
       // $article->translateOrNew('en')->text = ['texten'];
       // $article->translateOrNew('ka')->name = ['nameka'];
       // $article->translateOrNew('ka')->text = ['textka'];






    // return $article;
    // exit();

   $service->save();

  return redirect()->back();
```

}

BLADE FOR CREATE + CSS (in background):

```
<form action="{{route('service.store')}}" method="POST">
     {{csrf_field()}}





    <div class="tabset">
  <!-- Tab 1 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" class="radio1" id="tab1" aria-controls="marzen" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Bosanski</label>
  <!-- Tab 2 -->
  <input type="radio" class="radio1" name="tabset" id="tab2" aria-controls="rauchbier">
  <label for="tab2">Engleski</label>
  {{-- <!-- Tab 3 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab3" aria-controls="dunkles">
  <label for="tab3">Dunkles Bock</label> --}}

  <div class="tab-panels">
    <section id="marzen" class="tab-panel">
      <h2>Dodaj novu uslugu</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
<lebal>Naslov*(bs)</lebal>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title2">
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
<lebal>Opis*(bs)</lebal>
<textarea class="form-control" name="content2"></textarea>
</div>
  </section>
    <section id="rauchbier" class="tab-panel">
      <h2>Dodaj novu uslugu</h2>
         <div class="form-group">
<lebal>Title (EN)</lebal>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
<lebal>Description (EN)</lebal>
<textarea class="form-control" name="content"></textarea>
</div>
    </section>
    <section id="dunkles" class="tab-panel">
      <h2>Tab3</h2>

    </section>
  </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
```

WEB.PHP:

```
Route::post('/create',[
 'uses' => 'ServicesController@store',
 'as' => 'service.store'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the tutorial.

The whole point of that implementation is that you don't have to worry about the model locale at all. The locale is set through the URL "/en/..."

So if you make a POST request to your model store URL like so :

```
POST /en/post {payload}
```

The App Locale of your laravel application will be automatically set before you even reach the `PostController@store` method.

Then, you can simply create your model like you would usually do (like in your exemple, that's correct) , and the model will be stored with the according locale.

Now that your model is initially created with the defined locale, you should be able to edit it in another language.

So you can go to this URL: `/en/post/:id/edit` then switch to another locale : `/fr/post/:id/edit` and you will notice that all input of the translatable fields are blank. That's normal because the 'fr' translation of that model doesn't exist yet.

You can thus fill the form with the 'fr' translated field, then save (update the model). And the translation will be saved. Your model is now translated :)

Hope this helps !

PS you can have a look at the example code here https://github.com/mydnic/Laravel-Multilingual-SEO-Example

Comment: Hi @Clément Rigo , Thanks, I have spent last 12 hours implementing your tutorial. It is great. I get what I need everything is fast and very very good.

I follow all of your tutorial, but how to write the controller and blade for the create can you extend here the controller for create and edit / update.

In blog tutorial you have for index and show, but how about create (inserting) storing and editing (update).

Comment: Hi Clement I will write new answer on this question, I have just created CREATE AND STORE FUNCTION WITH ALL DETAILS, and you can check and tell me do you suggest anything to change here or better way. 

P.S. Service instead of Post model. New Answer below with title: "ANSWER"!

Comment: Hi @clement , just to ask you this: 

Now when I try to add data with some of my old Models which using this type of route:

<form method="POST" action="/posts"> ;;;AND;;;  Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');

...It IS failing. What is the problem here now? When using the route with namespacing with " uses " in route everything working fine ?

Comment: When I implement this stage below then my old routes which use "url " in form POST method fails. Then I only can use the routes with "as" and "uses". Why ?......

use Request;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    // ...

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        $locale = Request::segment(1);

        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => $locale
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
    }

    // ...

}

Comment: make a post request to /en/post instead of just /post

Comment: I tried but again my route fails, it only works when I add ->name or " as " in route.?

Comment: Hi @clement rigo,, your tutorial is great now I have multilanguage site. I tried this above with routes but it fails again it only work when I set the ->name(); to the route, maybe it is must in this situation. because locale is dynamic and it cannot be set like just /en or similar.

Please if you can look at my new question REGARDING your tutorial. Thanks

LINK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379830/how-do-i-eager-load-with-or-similar-when-i-have-the-situation-like-below-post

Comment: @TarikS. you can check this newer and cleaner approach https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-build-an-efficient-and-seo-friendly-multilingual-architecture-in-laravel-v2

Comment: thanks very much clement rigo, your tutorial are great. Can you please tell me how to output in lang switcher not just lang code but rather language name ? THANKS...... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428428/how-do-i-fetch-name-of-locale-language-not-just-a-locale-string-but-rather-th

Comment: Hi clement, Can you please see this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287902/how-to-prevent-a-request-from-being-cached-for-language-switch-routing-laravel-s

Answer (score 0):

So based on the tutorial, you'll have a column in your posts table called `locale`
Then in your view, you can add a select field from which you can chose the locale

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="locale">Locale</label>
   <select id="locale" name="locale" class="form-control">
       <option value="en">English</option>
       <option value="fr">French</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Then in your controller add the following line:

```
$post->locale = $request->locale;
```

Put `locale` in your `$fillable` array within the post model.

Comment: Hi, but when I choose locale in this select it dont change the content down.