# Get name of Language instead of Locale name (in Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, multilingual

How do I fetch name of locale (language) not just a locale string, but rather the name of that language in LARAVEL?

```
{{ app()->getLocale() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding an entry to a translation file using Laravel Localization.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization

In `AppServiceProvider@boot` :

```
$language = Settings::get('language'); // Fetch saved language preference
$language = ($language === null) ? config('app.locale','ENG') : $language->value;

App::setLocale($language);

$languages = Cache::rememberForever('languages',
    function () {

        $walkable = File::directories(App()->basePath() . '/resources/lang');
        $output = [];

        array_walk($walkable,
            function($value) use (&$output) {

                $parts = explode('/', $value);
                $key = end( $parts );

                $require = $value . '/language.php';

                if (file_exists($require)) {
                    $output[$key] = require($require);
                }

            }
        );

    return $output;
});

config(['app.languages' => $languages]);
```

I then have an entry for each language in dir `resources/lang/LOCALE_ISO_3 (ENG/SPA/ITA...)/language.php`

```
<?php // Spanish (SPA)

return [
    'default' => 'Spanish',
    'locale' => 'Español'
];
```

[image]

To then get a list of available languages:

```
dd( config('app.languages') );
```

Results in:

```
array:3 [▼
  "ENG" => array:2 [▼
    "default" => "English"
    "locale" => "English"
  ]
  "ITA" => array:2 [▼
    "default" => "Italian"
    "locale" => "Italiano"
  ]
  "SPA" => array:2 [▼
    "default" => "Spanish"
    "locale" => "Español"
  ]
]
```

To get current active language:

```
dd(trans('language'));
```

Gives you:

```
array:2 [▼
  "default" => "English"
  "locale" => "English"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`Locale::getDisplayLanguage()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplaylanguage.php) to do this. The first parameter is the locale, the second is the language you want to output in.

```php
<?php
echo Locale::getDisplayName("en", "fr");
// Output: anglais
echo Locale::getDisplayName("en", "de");
// output: Englisch
echo Locale::getDisplayName("fr", "en");
// output: French
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel doesn't have this information. You need to add it manually by creating table or config with locales and their languages names.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer